# Как создать DataFrame из двумерного массива по столбцам?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть двумерный массив

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Хочу сделать DataFrame, чтобы каждый под-массив был столбцом а не строкой. Когда я использую `pd.DataFrame(lst)` я получаю:

```
   col1   col2   col3
0   1       2     3
1   4       5     6
```

А необходимо получить:

```
   col1   col2   
0   1       4     
1   2       5  
2   3       6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проще всего [транспонировать](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) получившийся фрейм данных:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst).T
```

результат:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```